# How to redirect (301) when changed routing translation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes

I am looking for an easy way to make redirects in my application.

SITUATION:

I have routes like this:

```
http://myapp.com/authors/5-hemingway/books/1-moby-dick
```

The routes are translated this way (using gem 'i18n_routing'):

```
http://myapp.com/acutores/5-hemingway/libros/1-moby-dick
```

Now, I changed translation of acutores to scriptores. Easy step but I'd like to redirect all routes that contained an old "acutores" resource name to routes with "scriptores" instead.

My guess is, I should play in routes.rb with:

```
match "/acutores" => redirect("/scriptores")
```

But how to do it efficiently for all cases where 'acutores' appear? (especially with nested routes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This redirects `/acutores/something` to `/scriptores/something` but fails with plain `/acutores`:

```
match "/acutores/*path" => redirect("/scriptores/%{path}")
```

This seems to handle both:

```
match "/acutores(/*path)" => redirect {|params| "/scriptores/#{params[:path]}"}
```

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing

--edit

This will get rid of all the trailing slashes:

```
match "/acutores(/*path)" => redirect{ |params| "/scriptores/#{params[:path]}".chomp("/") }
```

I had issues with browser caching redirects, so empty the cache after modifications.

Comment: Thanks, looks good, but I'm not sure if I want to have a slash after redirection. In Your solution "/acutores" goes to "/scriptores/". What to do in order to remove the last "/" ?

Comment: In the latter example you can script as you wish because thats a method with captured parts available in params hash.

Comment: Modified the answer because I had extra slash in the redirect part. Tested and it seems to work now.

Comment: It's close, but it fails in cases when params[:path] is not empty. Then I go to: No route matches "/scriptores4-mann" . The url should be with '/' when there is longer path and without '/' when this is the end of the path.

Comment: One question here: do You have an idea, how to implement the same behaviour in Rails 2 application?

Comment: I think you'd need to create a separate controller to handle redirection.

Comment: Nice! But, still, how do you redirect a path that has "/acutores?param_name=value" with the parameter? Currently matching "/acutores(*path)" doesn't work. (used example in the question for illustrating purposes)