# How to redirect from /:id to /:friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is is possible to force a 301 redirect when someone attempts to browse to a page using the old `/:id` URL, rather than than the preferred `/:friendly_id` link?

[Apparently such redirections help to tell Google that you have updated the link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58319/will-google-go-by-my-sitemap-xml-or-also-include-its-own-crawled-urls).. so it stops displaying the old non-friendly link.

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814063/how-to-redirect-301-when-changed-routing-translation

Comment: The trivial answer is to do what you'd expect: look up the friendly id and return the redirect.

Comment: In your controller, just do a redirect_to, passing as parameter your new route.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With the latest version of [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) (5.0.3 at the time of writing this answer) and Rails 4, I do this in the controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  ...

  private

  def set_item
    @item = Item.friendly.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to action: action_name, id: @item.friendly_id, status: 301 unless @item.friendly_id == params[:id]
  end
end
```

Here's a description of the `redirect_to` line, broken down piece by piece:

- `action: action_name` retains the action that you're connecting to (which can be show, edit, update, or destroy based on the `before_action` that's in place) so that if you're accessing `/items/1/edit` you will be redirected to `/items/pretty-url/edit`
- `id: @item.friendly_id` ensures that the URL you're being redirected to is the pretty URL
- `status: 301` sets the redirect to the status of 301, for SEO
- `unless @item.friendly_id == params[:id]` makes sure that we're not redirecting people who access `@item` through its pretty URL

Comment: This redirect will wipe out any params that were submitted with the original URL. For example, `/items/4?filter=new` will become `/items/item-slug-for-item-4`, dropping the `filter` param. To preserve params, use `redirect_to request.params.merge(id: @event.friendly_id), status: 301 unless @item.friendly_id == params[:id]`.

Answer (score 3):

just defined the redirection inside the routes file

```
get '/:old_id', to: redirect {|params, req| "/#{X.find(params[:old_id]).friendly_id}" }
```

Comment: An alternative: get "/url_before" => redirect("/url_after")

Answer (score 2):

While James Chevalier's answer is correct, you can extract this method to the ApplicationController in order to use with any model that uses FriendlyId:

```
def redirect_resource_if_not_latest_friendly_id(resource)
  # This informs search engines with a 301 Moved Permanently status code that
  # the show should now be accessed at the new slug. Otherwise FriendlyId
  # would make the show accessible at all previous slugs.
  if resource.friendly_id != params[:id]
    redirect_to resource, status: 301
  end
end
```

As you can see it's also unnecessary to pass a specific `action` key to `redirect_to`. Passing a Rails model to `redirect_to` will automatically attempt to access the `show` action on the associated collection resource route (assuming it's set up that way). That also means it's unnecessary to pass an `id` key since FriendlyId always returns the latest slug in the model's `#to_param`.

Not being a huge fan of `unless` (confusing semantics) I tend to shy away from it but that's more my personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

**Routes**

I don't think your routes are the problem here

The problem is the backend handling of the route (I.E whether it uses `friendly_id` or not). All Google will see is this:

```
domain.com/users/45 
domain.com/users/your_user
```

If both of those routes work, Google will be happy. I think you're alluding to the idea that if you change the routes to only handle `your_user`, you'll need to be able to get Google to appreciate the redirects

---

**Redirects**

Considering you can handle both `id` and `slug` in the backend (we have code for this if you want), I'd handle redirects using the [ActionDispatch::Routing::Redirection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html) class:

```
  #config/routes.rb
  begin  
    User.all.each do |u|
        begin
          get "#{u.id}" => redirect("#{u.slug}")
        rescue
        end
      end
  rescue
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Rich. Basically I want Google to forget the old /:id style links because these seem of less value to their page ranking system. Also, the URL highlighting in the results doesn't look as sweet. Do you think I am going about this the right way?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
          get "#{s.id}" => redirect "#{s.slug}"

Comment: Should be `u.id`and `u.slug` sorry

Comment: Actually I stopped the error with "#{u.id}" => redirect("#{u.slug}") but the redirect doesn't appear to be happening.

Comment: Hi Rich, it doesn't throw the error, but it still isn't providing a redirect when I load up users/1

Comment: Perhaps off topic, but for the record, Google is happier if there is only a single URL for a given "page."  If there are more, they will consider it duplicate content, and in extreme cases is can hurt your site's ranking.  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you need to define both routes on your `config/routes.rb`

```
get 'path/:id' => 'controller#action'
get 'path/:friendly_id' => 'controller#action_2'
```

then in your legacy `action` method you need to provide a

```
return redirect_to controller_action_2_path(friendly_id: friendly_id),
                   status: :moved_permanently
```

this will generate a `301` response code. Which will eventually make bots start hitting your new pattern, without losing any of your traffic or indexing (SEO).