# How to test a 301 redirection with Minitest on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, minitest

Using Rails 6, I'm redirecting from native ids (`/users/id`) to friendly_ids (`/users/username`) (following the answer brought [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36731687/11293450)) which handles the redirect as such:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def redirect_resource_if_not_latest_friendly_id(resource)
    if resource.friendly_id != params[:id]
      redirect_to resource, status: 301
    end
  end
end
```

In my controller, I call the method as such:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show]

  def show
    redirect_resource_if_not_latest_friendly_id(set_user)
  end

  protected

  def set_user
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

It's working fine and I want to include the redirection in my test suite. I found answer and topics about how to do that with Rspec but I'm using Minitest and couldn't figure it out.

I tried a bunch of different ways (with params[:id], etc.) but to keep it simple let's say it's the following fixture, test and result.

Here is the fixture:

```
# test/fixtures/users.yml
one:
  username: username
  email: email@example.com
  slug: username
```

Here is the test:

```
# test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb  
class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should 301 redirect to the friendly_id" do
    @user = users(:one)
    get user_path(@user)
    assert_redirected_to "/users/#{@user.slug}"
  end
end
```

Here is the result of the test:

```
FAIL["test_should_301_redirect_to_the_friendly_id", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007fe716c66600 @name="UsersControllerTest">, 0.7785789999979897]
 test_should_301_redirect_to_the_friendly_id#UsersControllerTest (0.78s)
        Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:8:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How's the action for `user_path` defined?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I edited the question with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using the "whole" user record to make the request, so when you do

```
user_path(@user)
```

The route extracts the friendly_id from the resource and then your condition is evaluated to false, because the resource.friendly_id is always going to be the same as the id coming from the params.

Try instead:

```
get user_path(id: @user.id)
```

That way you can explicitly pass the @user.id through the params.

Comment: It's still getting the error:  `Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>`

Comment: Completely different problem, see the updated answer @NZisKool.

Answer (score 0):

possible the problem `resource.friendly_id != params[:id]` as I understood they are the same

Comment: But there’s still an actual redirect, do you have an idea of how I could assess it?